# Как разделить строку после того, как некий символ встретился N раз?

Tags: c#

Есть строка символов "1111,2222,3333,4444,5555"

Как разделить её после того, как символ "," встретится 3й раз?
чтобы получить
1111,2222,3333, и 4444,5555
Как разделить строку после того, как некий символ встретился N раз?

```
string[] data = `Str.Split`

  (new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

делит cразу после первого.

Возможно есть какое-то ниндзюцу для Str.Split, чтобы засунуть в параметы маску  типа

`{","},{any symbols},{","}`
обновил описание.
При использовании метода от EvgeniyZ

```
Str.Split(new[]{','}, 3).
```

Если его применить так

```
string str2 = "1111,2222,3333,4444,5555";

string[] data1 = str2.Split(new string[] {","}, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine($"{data1[0]}, \n {data1[1]}, \n {data1[2]}");
```

получаем

```
1111,
 2222,
 3333,4444,5555
```

но ожидаемый результат

```
1111,2222,3333,
4444,5555
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на будущее, как я отредактировал ваш текст, выделив код и выражение. (И "зразу" поменял на "сразу").

Comment: [`Str.Split(new[]{','}, 3)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-int32)).

Comment: Что в итоге нужно получить: `tttt,tttt,tttt` и `tttt,tttt`? Или `tttt,tttt,tttt`, `tttt`, `tttt`? Или что?

Comment: обновил описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод для получения всех индексов указанного символа (`searchstring`) в строке:

```
public static class StrExtention
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string searchstring)
    {
        int minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring);
        while (minIndex != -1)
        {
            yield return minIndex;
            minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring, minIndex + searchstring.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Сам алгоритм:

```
var str = "1111,2222,3333,4444,5555"; //строка
var n = 2;
var needIndex = str.AllIndexesOf(",").ElementAt(n - 1) + 1; //берём индекс 2 запятой
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                       .Select(x => str.Substring(x * needIndex, x == 0 ? needIndex : str.Length - x * needIndex))
                       .ToList();
```

P.S. Не знал, как красивее сделать `x == 0 ? needIndex : str.Length - x * needIndex` этот момент, поэтому решил просто сделать в лоб. Если есть предложения, как это красивее сделать, напишите в комментариях - поправлю

Результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это жесть как круто. Спасибо. Жаль нету Regex для этого чтобы просто в аргументах сплита поместить инденс.